# understanding destructured arguments to recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I am working on a problem in which an array is passed as a destructured argument to a function which is then used to recursively double the value of each number element in the array. (The purpose of the exercise is to devise a solution **without using array helper methods**)

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3] 
// should return '[2, 4, 6]'
```

Here's the solution I've found:

```
function double([first, ...rest]) {
  if (rest.length) {
    return [first * 2, ...double(rest)];
  } else {
    return [first * 2];
  }
}
```

(FWIW I've also noticed that this solution will work when you omit the `else` condition.)

I'm struggling to understand how the operation `first * 2` in the second block gets translated to `rest` as a parameter to `...double(rest)`. Any relevant input / references would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about `return [first * 2];` in the `else` block? It doesn't have anything to do with `rest`.

Comment: It's recursive, it takes in any number of arguments. The first argument is always defined as `first`, while the rest of the arguments uses rest arguments, and would be an array.  
Then it passes those arguments to next recursive call, where the first number in the `rest` array would be passed as `first` to next call etc. until there are no more arguments

Comment: It would be slightly better practice to make the null check be for the case of the empty array (in which case `first` will be `undefined`, and you should return `[]`). Then it would work with an empty array an input, which is not the case now.

Comment: @torazaburo thank you for pointing that out, I will refactor accordingly

Comment: @adeneo To be precise, it does not *take in any number of arguments*. It takes a single argument, an array, with any number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down you code...

```
[first, ...rest] = [1,2,3] //returns first = 1; rest = [2,3]
```

In the second call, without using the spread..

```
[1 * 2, double(rest)] //rest = [2,3]
[first, ...rest] = [2,3] //returns first = 2, rest = 3
[1*2, [2*2, double(rest)]
```

In the third call, without using the spread..

```
[1*2, [2*2, double(rest)]//rest = [3]
[first, ...rest] = [2,3] //returns first = 2, rest = [3]
[1*2, [2*2, [3*2]]
```

which gives `[2,[4,[6]]]`

By using the `...double()` instead of `double()`, the array will be flatten and returned as `[2,4,6]`

Below is the example without `spread(...)`

```js
function double([first, ...rest]) {
  if (rest.length) {
    return [first * 2, double(rest)];
  } else {
    return [first * 2];
  }
}

console.log(double([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: lovely! I see now how I was overlooking the flattening aspect of using this destructured syntax